# How many Strobogrammatic numbers are there from 0 to 99999

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, no-computers

0,1,2,5,8,11,69,96 are  Strobogrammatic numbers.

We call a   Strobogrammatic numbers if:

> When it is typed on a calculator, and the calculator is spun 180 degrees, the number visually looks the same.

How many    Strobogrammatic numbers are there from 0 to 99999?

**This is a no-computer puzzle; only the first right answer with explanation will be accepted.**

Comment: When your calculator use a segment-display, 1 would not be spin-able number (use segment b and c, but turned, it would be segment e and f). And if it use a other display, no Number would be a spin-able Number. Are leading zeros allowed, so that 020, 050, 080 or 0220 are are spin-able numbers?

Comment: When I spin my calculator by 180 degrees, the only digits I see are the serial number.

Comment: For reference, these are the [Strobogrammatic numbers](https://oeis.org/A018846)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

assumption: we can not usually have leading zeroes on a calculator, they are usually stripped.

> the spinnable digits are 0, 1, 2, 5, (6/9), and 8
>
> **For 1 digit**
>
>  Pos 1: we can have any of the five non-paired options (0 is not stripped in this one instance, as 0 is displayed on the calculator)
>
> Total: 5
>
> **For 2 digits:**
>
>  Pos 1: we can have any of the six non-zero spinnable digits
>  Pos 2: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 1
>
>  Total 6x1 = 6
>
>  **For 3 digits:**
>
>  Pos 1: we can have any of the six non-zero spinnable digits
>  Pos 2: we can have any of the five self-referential spinnable digits
>  Pos 3: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 1
>
>  Total 6x5x1 = 30
>
>  **For 4 digits:**
>
>  Pos 1: we can have any of the six non-zero spinnable digits
>  Pos 2: we can have any of the seven spinnable digits
>  Pos 3: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 2
>  Pos 4: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 1
>
>  Total: 6x7x1x1 = 42
>
>  **For 5 digits**
>
>  Pos 1: we can have any of the six non-zero spinnable digits
>  Pos 2: we can have any of the seven spinnable digits
>  Pos 3: we can have any of the five self-referential spinnable digits
>  Pos 4: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 2
>  Pos 5: we can only have the inverse digit of pos 1
>
>  Total: 6x7x5x1x1 = 210
>
>  Thus all spinnable numbers from 0 to 99999 is the sum:
>  5+6+30+42+210 = 293

So:

> There are 293 spinnable numbers between 0 and 99999

Comment: 2 spun around is still 2, not 5, just like 5 spun around is still 5, not 2.

Comment: Beside Josh comment, there are more than 195 numbers.

Comment: @Josh ugh, you are right, brain is clearly not working, that bumps up the multiplications a bit, i'll amend

Comment: @crcroberts Well done, green tick and upvote four you !!

Comment: Heh, seems I'm WAY off. Time to go to sleep. Work all day with numbers, forget how to use them at night. :p

Answer (score 5):

Late, but different approach.

> Self spinnable numbers: 0, 1, 2, 5, 8
>  Spinnable pair: 6 and 9
>
>  **1 digit (5)**
>
>  All the self spinnable numbers
>
>  **2 digits (6)**
>
>  Self spinnable: 11, 22, 55, 88
>  Pair spinnable: 69, 96
>
>  **3 digits (30)**
>
>  Self spinnable: 1x1, 2x2, 5x5, 8x8
>  Pair spinnable: 6x9, 9x6
>
>  One digit spinnable numbers go into `x`
>  So, 6 x 5 = 30
>
>  **4 digits (42)**
>
>  Self spinnable: 1xx1, 2xx2, 5xx5, 8xx8
>  Pair spinnable: 6xx9, 9xx6
>
>  Two digits spinnable numbers (including 00) go into `xx`
>  So, 6 x 7 = 42
>
>  **5 digits (210)**
>
>  Self spinnable: 1xxx1, 2xxx2, 5xxx5, 8xxx8
>  Pair spinnable: 6xxx9, 9xxx6
>
>  Three digits spinnable numbers (including 000) go into `xxx`
>  So, 6 x (7 x 5) = 210
>
>  And, 5 + 6 + 30 + 42 + 210 is **293**.

Comment: I think the statement `including 000` in your 5 digits calculation should really be `including 0x0`, otherwise your calculation would be 6 x (30 + 1) instead of 6 x ((6+1) x 5).