# Square a 5 digits Strobogrammatic numbers

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Find a 5 digits [Strobogrammatic numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43230/how-many-strobogrammatic-numbers-are-there-from-0-to-99999),
so if we square it, the result is also a Strobogrammatic numbers.

We call a number Strobogrammatic if:

> When it is typed on a calculator, and the calculator is spun 180 degrees, the number visually looks the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the smallest such number is

> 10001

because

> $10001^2=100020001$

This also happens to be the [only solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qdkccewk/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cheeky answer:

> 00000^2 = 00000
>  
>  because an infinite string of 0's is still 0, and 0 squared is 0