# Find a Strobogrammatic number, so if we square it, the result is a pandigit number

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Find a [**Strobogrammatic number**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43230/how-many-strobogrammatic-numbers-are-there-from-0-to-99999), so that if we square it, the result is a **pandigit number**.

Note:

- A Strobogrammatic number is a number when typed on a calculator, and the calculator is spun 180 degrees, the number visually looks the same. (example 6229, 18881)
- A pandigit number is a number containing the digits 0-9, where each digit appears exactly once. (example 1234567890, 1203456789)
- Because there are only a few possibilities, I tagged this puzzle as [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number is

> 99066

When squared it becomes

> 9814072356

Explanation

> I cutdown the possible answers by doing the following: 
>  Determined the min strobogrammatic number to form a 10 digit number which was 3???? This gets rid of 1,2 as a leading digit (down from 210 to 140 possible answers) 
>  The pandigit number is divisible by 9 (sum of digits is divisible by 9) and if N^2 is divisible by 9 then N is divisible by 3 (and the sum of digits of N is divisible by 3 
>  Each number (x) in the center adds x mod 3 to the total of the digits so we have
>
> ```
>  0 mod 3 = 0 
>
>  1 mod 3 = 1 
>
>  2,5,8 mod 3 = 2
> ```
>
> Each number (2) in either of the outside numbers adds 2x mod 3 to the total (or in the case of 6,9 it adds 15 mod 0)
>
> ```
>  0*2 mod 3 = 0 
>
>  6+9 mod 3 = 0 
>
>  9+6 mod 3 = 0 
>
>  2*2 mod 3 = 1 
>
>  5*2 mod 3 = 1 
>
>  8*2 mod 3 = 1 
>
>  1*2 mod 3 = 2
> ```
>
> So we need to choose 2 of the outside digits (only can choose one 0) and 1 of the inner digits
>  At this point I just tried a few numbers (and happily stated at high numbers) although to carry it through for a final possibility of numbers
>  Regex shows 1,2,3rd numbers, 4th and 5th are set based on the first 2 numbers
>
> ```
>  +----------------+---------------+
>
>  |    Regex       | Possibilities |
>
>  +----------------+---------------+
>
>  | [58][069][258] |            18 |
>
>  | [58][258]1     |             6 |
>
>  | [58]10         |             2 |
>
>  | [69][069]0     |             6 |
>
>  | [69][258][258] |            18 |
>
>  | [69]11         |             2 |
>
>  +----------------+---------------+
> ```
>
> Gives a total of 52 possible inputs.
>  Which is still a fair number to try by hand and I'll admit I didn't realize no computer also meant no calculator until this morning, I thought it was mainly to prevent coded brute force solutions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you go about getting to this number?  Just trying stuff?

Comment: @DanRussell I think just trying stuff. The number must be a 5 digits number, and there are only 210 strobogrammatic 5 digits numbers.

Comment: Right, I was just wondering if there was a rationale other than "just try all 210".

Comment: And the number must be divisible by 3

Comment: @DanRussell I added some explanation I didn't yesterday as I was on my phone.  I don't know if there is a way to cut it down to less then 52 possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

16969691 is the smallest Strobogrammatic prime, so if we square it, the result is a pandigital number :

16969691^2 = 287970412635481

....K.D. Bajpai

Comment: the result of the squaring does not result in a pandigital number as outlined by the OP